# Adding 1 to all second elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to add 1 to all second elements but I am running into a "level" problem I believe here is my code:

```
list2 = {{{5, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{7, 1}}, {{2, 3}}}

r1pow = Map[(# + {{0, 1}}) &, list2]
```

the result I got is:

```
{{{5, 2}}, {{0, 1}} + {{2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}}
```

my desired result is:

```
{{{5, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}}
```

as you can see it is giving a problem for my second element {{2, 1}, {3, 1}}, how can i fix this problem?

Comment: `list2[[All, All, 2]] = list2[[All, All, 2]] + 1` or shorter `list2[[All, All, 2]]++`

Comment: Before hitting the site with similar questions please take the time to understand the answers to [your earlier ones.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46880/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way:

```
list2 = {{{5, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{7, 1}}, {{2, 3}}};
list2 /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> {a, b + 1}

(* {{{5, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

I closed this question a few minutes ago, but I just reopened it because I see that you are specifically asking about fixing your code rather than how to perform a certain operation.  You can use this:

```
Map[# + {0, 1} &, list2, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{5, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}}
> ```

- I removed the extraneous set of brackets
- I added a *levelspec* of `{2}`

In recent versions you should also be able to use `MapAt` which would be somewhat cleaner:

```
MapAt[# + 1 &, list2, {All, All, 2}]
```

Usually faster however is to use the methods you have already been shown by Kuba and now rasher, and discussed further in [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns).  I still suspect that this question would not have been asked if you properly understood that method.

Comment: what method are you speaking of?

Comment: @Crisp Sorry, I thought that was clear.  I mean using `Part` as in `list2[[All, All, 2]]++` or `list2[[All, All, 2]] += 7`.  Please look at the documentation for `Part`, `Increment`, and `AddTo`.  My preference for `Part` is explained [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121).

Comment: ok thank you very much, will do.

Answer (score 3):

Showing some of the newer functions

```
list = {{{5, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{7, 1}}, {{2, 3}}};
```

**1.**

`ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[list, x : {a_, b_} :> {a, b + 1}, {All, All}]
```

{{{5, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}}

**2.**

`Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
# + Threaded[{0, 1}] & /@ list
```

{{{5, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}}

**3.**

`ApplyTo` (new in 12.2)

If we want to change the original list inline:

```
list //= MapAt[# + {0, 1} &, {;; , ;;}];

list
```

{{{5, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}}

Answer (score 3):

Supporting @eldo in an effort of good house maintenance as much as I can.

We can use [**`Query`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html)

```
Query[All, {1 -> ( # + {0, 1} &)}]@list
```

> `{{{5, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}}`

Answer (score 2):

Using `Cases` and `Map`:

```
list2 = {{{5, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{7, 1}}, {{2, 3}}};

Cases[list2, x_ :> First@Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]] + 1} &, {x}, {2}]]

(*{{{5, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{7, 2}}, {{2, 4}}}*)
```